# ¿Por qué me da error al implementar el método de ordenamiento QuickSort?

Tags: java, ordenamiento, quicksort

Mi método:

```
public void ordQuicksort(int arreglo[], int primero, int ultimo) {
    int i, j, pivote, auxiliar;
    i = primero;
    j = ultimo;
    pivote = arreglo[(primero + ultimo) / 2];

    do {//mover indices
        while (arreglo[i] < pivote) {
            i++;
        }
        //mover indices
        while (arreglo[j] > pivote) {
            j--;
        }//aqui hacemos el intercambio
        if (i <= j) {
            auxiliar = arreglo[i];
            arreglo[i] = arreglo[j];
            arreglo[j] = auxiliar;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    } while (i <= j);

    if (primero < j) {
        ordQuicksort(arreglo, primero, j);
    }
    if (i < ultimo) {
        ordQuicksort(arreglo, i, ultimo);
    }

    mostrarArreglo(arreglo);
}
```

Así lo imprimo en mi jTextArea con mi boton "Ordenar"

```
    int[] arreglo={};

    arreglo= new int[N_ingresados.getSize()];
    for (int i = 0; i < N_ingresados.getSize(); i++)
    {
        arreglo[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(N_ingresados.getElementAt(i)));

        ordQuicksort(arreglo, 0, arreglo.length-1);
        jtxaOrdenado.setText(Arrays.toString(arreglo));
```

Cabe recalcar que ordeno los números que están ingresados en mi JList.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

No he visto que obtuvieras en ningún momento el modelo de la lista ni lo trataras, creo que ahí estaba el error, el siguiente código basado en tu problema funciona perfectamente.

> Los campos que he utilizado para aplicar tu problema.

```
    Integer[] miArregloEntero;
    JList<Integer> miJList = null;
    JTextArea miJTextArea = null;
```

> Aquí realizas lo que haga falta para ir almacenándolos en un array de Integer.

```
    /* Datos */ miArregloEntero = new Integer[]{20,10,15,8,20};
```

> Aquí vas 'pegando' el array cada vez que haya cambios. Recuerda borrar los datos antes.

```
    /* Eliminas datos */ miJList.removeAll();
    /* Objeto que contiene los Datos */ miJList = new JList<>(miArregloEntero);
```

> Cuando quieras ordenar y actualizar datos haces esto.

```
    /* Ordenas */ ordQuicksort(miArregloEntero, 0, miArregloEntero.length-1);
    /* Introduces datos ordenados */ miJList.setListData(miArregloEntero);
```

> Si quieres recorrer los datos del JList.

```
    /* Obtienes modelo de los Datos */ ListModel<Integer> modeloLista = miJList.getModel();
    /* Recorres y muestras datos ya ordenaddos de miJList */
    for(int i = 0; i < modeloLista.getSize(); i++) System.out.println(modeloLista.getElementAt(i));
```

> Para obtener la lista ordenada en tu JTextArea.

```
    /* Introduces en miJTextArea el array ordenado apoyado en la clae Arrays y su método estático toString. */
    miJTextArea = new JTextArea(Arrays.toString(miArregloEntero));
```

Comment: Ya lo remplaze y nada :/ me sigue ordennado tal y como esta en la imagen.

Comment: @LuisVidal He actualizado la respuesta con el código completo basado en tu problema, si tienes razón sobre el algoritmo, no sé muy bien que leí en la primera edición desde el móvil :).